# Using array_count_values and getting "Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!" error

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-4

I'm trying to add 4 arrays into one array (`$all_prices`) and then check the values of each key in each individual array against `$all_prices` to make sure that they are unique. If they are not I want to add a `0` to the end of if to make it unique (so `0.50` becomes `0.500`).

For some reason I'm getting the following error, despite the fact that I already changed the data type from decimal to varchar:

> array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!

***Edit***
Here is a snippet from dd($all_prices)

```
array(4) { [0]=> array(9) { ["14.45"]=> string(8) "sample 1" ["12.40"]=> 
string(8) "sample 2" ["14.13"]=> string(8) "sample 3" ["15.11"]=> 
string(8) "sample 4"
```

Code:

```
$all_prices   = [$list_a_prices, $list_b_prices, $list_c_prices, $list_d_prices];
$price_count  = array_count_values($all_prices);

foreach($list_b_prices as $key => $value){
    if($price_count[$key] >= 2){
        $key . "0";
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong? Is there is a way to leave the data type as Decimal?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the output of `var_dump($all_prices);`?

Comment: It just keeps going but I put a snippet to give you an idea, thanks.

Comment: I notice that it doesn't say "string" for the prices, but I set the database table to save the price as a Varchar, so it should be a string right? Or do I need to do something else as well?

Comment: Nope, that wouldn't change anything. `array_count_values()` requires a single-dimensional array, but you're supplying a 2-dimensional array. The function can't search inside arrays — you need to flatten the array first. So create a new array containing all the values you need, and then apply the function, and it should work.

Comment: AHHHH, so something like $all_prices    = []+$list_a_prices+... etch would work?

Comment: Don't forget to put your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help. You're simply merging the non-duplicate keys of an empty array (`[])` with the rest of the values. The array needs to be single-dimensional. Try something like this: `foreach ($list_b_prices as $sub) { foreach ($sub as $key => $value) { $result[$key] = $value; } }`. And then use `$results` with `array_count_values()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not index by the prices, after all from a math point of view 5.0 and 5.00 does not make difference at all.

If you are obtaining values from a database you will get strigs everywhere. So you will have to cast (int)$key for the keys.

And in your foreach you are changing a temporary variable. $key exists only for the current iteration of the loop you will want to declare it as:

```
foreach($list_b_prices as &(int)$key => $value){
    if($price_count[$key] >= 2){
        $key . "0";
    }
}
```

Note the ampersand and the casting to integer. Although i'm not sure which will come first. But again: I think indexing by some different value shall give you a better result.

Comment: No, that would simply not work. You can't do `&(int)$key` — it will result in a syntax error. Plus, this doesn't solve the problem here; `array_count_values()` requires a single-dimensional array with scalar values in it, and currently the OP's array contains **other arrays**.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right, I'm not quite sure about his end goals, but if you want unique keys indexing by prices, well not a good idea. That's why I am suggesting choosing a different index in first place.

Comment: Well I used $all_prices  = []+$list_a_prices+... and plugged it into array_count_values and got a normal looking response. So at least that part worked.

Comment: But now I'm getting a "Undefined index: 15.66" error message. 15.66 is the first price from $list_b_prices

Comment: Could you rather tell us what is it you trying to do? Sort by prices?

Comment: I'm setting prices for a drop down menu with database prices

Comment: So since I'm using Laravel (php) I have to make sure that every key in the associative array is unique or they will over ride each other

Comment: Amal shall definatley have a solution for you on the chat, but if I were doing that I would set an array for each price, not a string. The array can contain multiple items with the same price. Simply adding 0 digits at the end, will get even more a hassle with adding in items.

Answer (score 1):

What about a nested loop ?

```
$all_prices   = [$list_a_prices, $list_c_prices, $list_d_prices];

foreach($list_b_prices as $key => $value){
    foreach($all_prices as $array){
        if(isset($array[$key])){
            $list_b_prices[$key] .= '0';
        }
    }
}
```

Not elegant but it does the trick.

Comment: My question is if I have 3 of the same prices (I won't have control over the prices in the future, that will be someone else) will it change the 2nd two instances the same way. For example if there are 3 prices of "1.99", the first match will become "1.990" which is great but won't the second match to the original "1.99" also be made into "1.990"?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, but I just noticed that the code I posted contains a bug : it will compare the values of $list_b_prices against themselves at the second second foreach iteration, appending 0s to all of its elements. To fix this, you can either exclude $list_b_prices from $all_prices or add a === check inside the second loop. I'll edit it right away.

Comment: To try and answer your question : if there are three similar prices in $list_a_prices, $list_b_prices and $list_d_prices, the code will check against the one in $list_a_prices first and append a 0 to the value that is inside $list_b_prices. When the (second) loop gets to $list_d_prices, the conflicting value will already have been modified by the previous iteration, so the isset will return false.

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense, would it change anything if there were two prices in the same array? (Sorry to be so nitpicky, its just that I won't have any control of the prices in the future and my friend would never remember to check for duplicate prices later on). So for example if list_a had "1.99" price and list_b had two "1.99" prices, would the two 1.99 prices in the second list be made into 1.990 and 1.9900 or into 1.990 and another 1.990?

Comment: I guess the curx of my question is will the newly created number be checked against the $all_prices array and modified as needed as well?

Comment: Within the same array ? In the var_dump you posted, the prices are the keys so if there were two similar prices, one of them would overwrite the other before it even gets to the loop.

I'm starting to get the feeling that this solution getting unnecessary complex, maybe there is a better way to approach the problem ?

Comment: Lol sorry, that was my mistake I forgot I explained what I was doing with this info on a different answer. The reason I'm going through all this is because I'm going to use these arrays to populate a drop-down menu via php, which means that I can't have two keys be the same.

Comment: The easiest way I've found to work around this is to simply add a "0" to the end of the number behind the decimal (turning 0.50 into 0.500 for example). But as I will not have control of prices in the future I'm trying to automate this process.

Comment: But you're right, I had originally intended to do something else with the arrays as well but I can change that. But also I'm realizing that if I add all of these arrays together, and if there are duplicates, it will already be too late to check for duplicates because they would have already overridden each other, correct?

Comment: Are the samples guaranteed to have different names in the $list_x_prices arrays ? If so, maybe you can use them as keys instead of the prices, that would eliminate the problem of having to deal with duplicate keys.

Comment: Great idea. And yes, the samples should always have a different name.

Comment: So flip how I create the array, with the names as the key, then build a big array of all the names, then check for duplicate values (the prices) and add "0"'s to them if they are not unique. Then flip the array back to having the prices as keys so that I can populate the drop-down menu. Lol. Awesome.

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind, but it's interesting. I was gonna suggest passing them to the drop down menu with the names as keys and the prices as values, then modify the... ah this is confusing. What does the drop down menu look like though ? Are the prices displayed inside the option attribute or is it the names ?

Comment: Lol. The drop down has the name, the values are populated in a different input via JS.